# 'Routes' is not defined react/jsx-no-undef

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So I was following the React Crash Course on YouTube for Beginners from Academind. I was following everything along and everything was good until I came to the Routing part.
I followed every step, everything just perfectly (for the routing part) but after refreshing the page the following error occurs:

> A `<Route>` is only ever to be used as the child of `<Routes>` element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your `<Route>` in a `<Routes>`.

Aaand I did it, I wrapped my Route in Routes :

```
    import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';


import AllMeetupsPage from './Pages/AllMeetups';
import NewMeetupsPage from './Pages/NewMeetups';
import FavoritesPage from './Pages/Favorites';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/'>
          <AllMeetupsPage />
        </Route>

        <Route path='/new-meets'>
          <NewMeetupsPage />
        </Route>

        <Route path='/favs'>
          <FavoritesPage />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and then I get this:

> 'Routes' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef

then I :

Tried to import **Routes** from ***react-router-dom*** - No success;

Tried to import **Routes** from ***react-router*** - No success;

Tried to import **Routes** also in different components - No success;

Trust me I tried every different scenario for **Routes** but couldnt achieve anything different.
I

Googled, researched and couldnt find the solution for this problem.. Now Im desperate and
stuck here and I cant continue my React learning journey if I dont fix this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the thing was, that I was following a guide for the older react-router-dom;

In order to fix that, I just read the new docs for react-router-dom@6;

There is no `<Switch>` now, instead you wrap your APP in  just like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Then in the App component, you wrap your content in `<Routes>` and for every different path we use `<Route> </Route>` or just `<Route />`, depends on your project.

Theres my example, just to be more clear:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
    <MainNavigation/>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<AllMeetups />}></Route>
        <Route path="/new-meetups" element={<NewMeetups />}></Route>
        <Route path="/favorites" element={<Favorites />}></Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Didn't help. Read docs and i am doing everything correct, but Routes can't be recognized in my import ...

Answer (score 2):

Try to run `yarn add react-router`, then `import {Routes,Route} from 'react-router'`

Answer (score 1):

```
1)npm i add react-router-dom;
2)import {  BrowserRouter as Router,  Routes,  Route} from "react-router-dom";
3)`function App() { return (
  <Router>
   <Routes>
     <Route path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard />} />
     <Route path='/login' element={<Login/>} />
   </Routes>
 </Router>
);
}export default App;`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `import { BrowserRouter as Routes, Route } from react-router-dom`

Docs: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: Thank you for your fast response, I tried it and now I get


> You cannot render a `<Router>` inside another `<Router>`. You should never have more than one in your app.

Comment: Did you change something else in your code?

Answer (score 0):

```js
import {Link,Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom'

    <Routes>
        <Route path="/about" element={About}/>
        <Route path="/home" element={Home}/>
    </Routes>
```

This is working for me.
If it doesn't work for you, maybe you need to reinstall `react-router-dom` package.

Answer (score 0):

The `Routes` component belongs to the `react-router` module which is taken as a dependency by the `react-router-dom` module, try the below code, as it imports the components separately.

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom"
import { Route, Routes} from "react-router";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"`

- make sure you wrote Routes and not Router or you'll get an error like `You cannot render a <Router inside another <Router error ...`

Answer (score -1):

in place of `Routes` you should use `Switch`
[nested routes](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start/2nd-example-nested-routing)

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

    function App() {
      return (
        <div>
<Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route path='/'>
              <AllMeetupsPage />
            </Route>
    
            <Route path='/new-meets'>
              <NewMeetupsPage />
            </Route>
    
            <Route path='/favs'>
              <FavoritesPage />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
</Router>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: Hello, seems good but I got 
`*Attempted import error: 'Switch' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.*`,
tried only with `'react-router'`, same result.

Comment: what is the version of react-router-dom you are using?

Comment: `"react-router-dom": "^6.0.2",`

Comment: can you please try wrapping up Switch with Router, I have updated the answer